# Can I hide the query tab in the Azure Data Explorer portal for certain users?

Tags: dashboard, azure-data-explorer, kql, monaco-editor

When I click on https://dataexplorer.azure.com, I see the Kusto dashboard page with the default tabs "*start*", "*data*", "*query*" and "*dashboards*". Now I would like to provide dashboards for some users, but no query access to the tables.

- Is it possible to hide the query tab for those users ?

I know that there is a workaround by [embedding the portal in an iframe](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/monaco/host-web-ux-in-iframe). This is more a kind of workaround as it requires an own web page to be set up and maintained. I am thinking about a solution for administrators, e.g. by assigning dashboard roles.

Comment: You can use [database level security role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/manage-database-security-roles#database-level-security-roles)

Comment: I think using database level security could be a work around in general. The Kusto roles are quite simple (only Admin, User and Viewer). As a consequence, we would have to set all tables by default to restricted_view_access = true. This works for smaller clusters and a few users, but it will make operations quite complex when tables are continously being created and changed.

Comment: When `monitors` role is chosen, You cannot query the entire database

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Aswin ! That will do it for me !

Comment: just to complete this post for others reader: visibility may also be limited by adding row level security function and respective AAD roles. See Kusto RLS documentation  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [database level security role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/manage-database-security-roles#database-level-security-roles) to apply security to database level.

| Role | Permissions |
| --- | --- |
| admins | View and modify the database and database entities. |
| users | View the database and create new database entities. |
| viewers | View tables in the database where RestrictedViewAccess isn't turned on. |
| unrestrictedviewers | View the tables in the database even where RestrictedViewAccess is turned on. The principal must also have admins, viewers or users permissions. |
| ingestors | Ingest data to the database without access to query. |
| monitors | View database metadata such as schemas, operations, and permissions. |

**Table Reference:**  [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/manage-database-security-roles#database-level-security-roles) on database security roles on kusto.

```
.add database <db-name> <role> ('aaduser=****.com')
```

Replace `<db-name>` with the respective database name; Replace `<role>`  with `monitors`.